# GA API - Getting Product Info Associated to Sku

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm running into an issue that I'm hoping someone might know how to resolve. In the reporting api, I can get information based on a sku. Something like so:

```
  {
    'reportRequests': [{
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [
        {"expression": "ga:productDetailViews"},
        {"expression": "ga:itemQuantity"},
        {"expression": "ga:uniquePurchases"},
        {"expression": "ga:itemRevenue"}
      ],
      'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:productSku'}]
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is great for getting the data tied to a sku, but I was wondering if there is a way to get additional product information for each sku rather than metric information. For example, given a set of skus, I'd like to see the category hierarchy (section, category, subcategory) as well as the product name:

```
SKU, Name,   Section,Category,  Subcategory
1,   Blah,   Shoes,  Basketball,
2,   Another,Shoes,  Soccer,    Mens
...
```

Given that information like this is all correlated on a page when sent from a website, I don't see why this shouldn't be possible.

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Blah',
    'category': 'Shoes/Basketball',
});
```

Adobe has something similar with their Saint Classifications and I was hoping it would be something possible to get out of GA. I can't seem to find anything like this across any of the apis, so am hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you look to have specified categories with the correct '/' delimiter you can use the dimension ga:productCategoryLevelXX, you do need to have at least one metric in your request but you could do something like

```
  {
    'reportRequests': [{
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{"expression": "ga:productDetailViews"}],
      'dimensions': [
        {"expression": "ga:productSku"},
        {"expression": "ga:productCategoryLevel1"},
        {"expression": "ga:productCategoryLevel2"},
        {"expression": "ga:productCategoryLevel3"}
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought doing multiple dimensions would be drilling down, but this doesn't seem to be the case. This looks like it works as long as the product implementation was always one to one, sku to category. I've been testing some implementations that don't have them one to one (sometimes hundreds to a single sku), so I'll have to figure out some logic to handle those cases.